# Facebook fql query pass it to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook

I am developing a Facebook application and I have this code here which queries the user id and other information:

```
$users = $facebook->api(array(
  'method' => 'fql.query',
  'query' =>    "SELECT uid, last_name, pic_big"
             + " FROM user WHERE uid IN ("
             + "     SELECT uid" 
             + "     FROM page_fan"
             + "     WHERE page_id='411133928921438'" 
             + "         AND uid IN ("
             + "             SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()"
             + "         )"
             + ")"
));
```

I need to store the user id in an array so I can send invitations only to the users in the generated array.

```
function newInvite(){
    var user_ids = ["1368246891", "1206927311", "1149862205"];
    FB.ui({ 
      'method' : 'apprequests',
      'message': 'There goes the message for Penelope App users to invite their friends',
      'to'     : user_ids,
    });
}
```

The user_ids must be in the array which holds the user id genrated from the fql query...

Comment: do you know that sending requests this way is possible only to users who are friends of the sender ?

Comment: Yes, i do, that's the point...

Comment: what errors do you run into ?

Comment: I don't have any error here.. i just want that the var user_ids to be populated automatically with the id's taken from the fql query...